# no basic auth credentials for - `docker push image_name`

Tags: docker, docker-image

We have our own private registry for the docker images. I get `no basic auth credentials` after executing command `docker push  image_name`. Has it to do with access rights to push newly build image on the private registry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your below file is not configured with the auths.

> ~/.docker/config.json

Update your config.json and add auths if not present already like below sample example.

```
{
        "auths": {
                "<account>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com": {},
                "https://<account>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com": {},
                "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {}
        },
        "HttpHeaders": {
                "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/18.09.2 (darwin)"
        },
        "credsStore": "<value>",
        "stackOrchestrator": "<value>"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I cross checked in my `/home/` and I do not have this `config.json`  file. Is it a autogenerated file?

Comment: Yes. You can log into any public or private repository for which you have credentials. When you log in, the command stores credentials in $HOME/.docker/config.json on Linux.

Comment: Well this resolved my issue. Thank you @Pacifist_AWS  :)

Comment: That's the correct config file but you shouldn't edit this file directly, use `docker login your_private_registry.com` instead and it will fill it automatically.